# I need help subtracting variables from one another, both being numbers

Tags: python, string, math, addition

So, I'm trying to code a text based adventure game to get used to Python. Basically, I'm working on health and attack etc. My health and attack values are

```
health=50
squidAttack=5
squidHealth=20
attack=5
```

So I then have defined

```
def squidAttack():
 global health
 global squidHealth
 global squidAttack
 health=health-squidAttack
```

but when I run I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                    
File "C:\Users\AaronC\Documents\Python\Krados.py", line 280, in
<module> squidAttack()                File
"C:\Users\AaronC\Documents\Python\Krados.py", line 253, in squidAttack
health=health-squidAttack                                             
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'function'
```

I would like to emphasise; I have no idea what any of the error means, and I have searched a lot but could not find anything. Please help.

Comment: "misusing strings from one another"?  I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: I think he misspelled "minusing" (i.e., subtracting) and may be confusing strings with variables.  I'm going to change the title.

Comment: Ditch the `global`s and read a decent tutorial.

Comment: defining variables in Python? No offense, but maybe you want to read about Python and maybe also about dynamically vs. static typed languages first

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same name, `squidAttack`, for both the variable and the function. Rename one of them and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
squidAttack = 5
# squidAttack is an int

# ... Code goes here ...

def squidAttack():
    # stuff goes here

# squidAttack is a function
```

When you define the `squidAttack` function, it redefines what was once an int.

A much better way to do this is to use classes

```
class Actor(object):
    def __init__(self, name, health, attack):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.attack = attack
    def attacks(other):
        other.health -= self.attack

me = Actor("Me", 50, 5)
squid = Actor("Squid", 20, 5)

squid.attacks(me)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the name `squidAttack` for both a variable containing the value `5` and a function for subtracting that variable from `health`.  Because the function comes last, it overrides the `5` meaning of `squidAttack`, and so when you try to do `health=health-squidAttack`, Python will use the function definition of `squidAttack` and try to subtract a function from an integer.  Obviously, this doesn't work.  You need to rename at least one of the `squidAttack`s so that they have different names.